# How can I put the value from an XML file into an array list in another class in java?

Tags: java, xml, class

I am reading in an XML file, and trying to return the values in another class using Java. In the XML Reader I read in the values from the XML file. I'm not quite sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class XMLReader {

    public static List<String> load()
    {

        try{

            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory =                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("C:/adapters.xml"));
            doc.normalize();

            NodeList rootNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("adapters");
            Node rootNode = rootNodes.item(0);
            Element rootElement = (Element) rootNode;
            NodeList adaptersList = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("class");

            for(int i=0; i<adaptersList.getLength(); i++){
                Node theAdapter = adaptersList.item(i);
                Element adpElement = (Element) theAdapter;

                System.out.println("This is: " + adpElement.getTextContent());
            }

        }catch(ParserConfigurationException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}


public class AdapterLoader {

    public static List<AbstractAdapter> loadAllAdapters()
    {
        List<AbstractAdapter> allAdapters = new ArrayList<AbstractAdapter>();

        List<String> adapterClasses = XMLReader.load();

        for (String className : adapterClasses)
        {
            try {
                Class adapters = Class.forName(className);
                AbstractAdapter adp = (AbstractAdapter) adapters.newInstance();
                allAdapters.add(adp);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return allAdapters;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seriously consider using JAXB. Life is too short for manual XML parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing it to console

```
System.out.println("This is: " + adpElement.getTextContent());
```

add this to a List and return that instead of

```
return null;
```

Comment: I have added it to a list, however when I try to return it, instead of printing it to the console, it states the list cannot be resolved to a variable.

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
             list.add(adpElement.getTextContent());

Comment: declare your list outside the try block and add data to the list in place of sys out and than return list instead of null.